# How to loop through all the elements on a page and delete all of them in selenium webdriver C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to loop through 44,022 items on a page and trying to delete all of them using Selenium Webdriver C#. Here is my code:

```
IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> attachments = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("attachment"));

foreach (IWebElement attachment in attachments)
{
    attachment.Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("delete-attachment")).Click();
    IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    alert.Accept();
}
```

But it runs and delete about 100 and then stop but never delete all of them. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: It's not showing any exception, it just started deleting them then just stop without showing any error or exception like if it's done.

Comment: How many elements are actually in your attachments list? All 44,022 or you were just expecting all of them to be in the list?

Comment: I'm expecting all of them to be in the list

Comment: Well then you should debug it and check how many elements are really in that list :)

Comment: I mean, I never created any list, the code I showed you that's the only code I have.

Comment: Oh okay, there is 44,022 on the page and I'm using it to click on each one of them and delete them.

Comment: Okay, I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `FindElements` either has a limit or that the Elements aren't currently being displayed and can therefore not be *found*.

You might want to try to do this recursively instead (I mean, if you are gonna delete everything anyway, I don't see the harm in this). You could try something like this:

```
public List<IWebElement> attachments;
public void RecursiveDeletion()
{
    this.attachments = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("attachment"));
    if (this.attachments.Count == 0) return;
    foreach (IWebElement attachment in this.attachments)
    {
        attachment.Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("delete-attachment")).Click();
        IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        alert.Accept();
    }
    RecursiveDeletion();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the page is lazy loading and all 44k aren't showing up until you scroll down or delete items. Since your initial fetch of items only occurs once (it's outside the loop), you never get the updates as items are deleted. If you just move your items fetch inside your loop, that should solve the problem.

```
foreach (IWebElement attachment in driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("attachment")))
{
    attachment.Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("delete-attachment")).Click();
    driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
}
```

Note: I also moved your Alert accept code into a single line. It's not needed, it just makes the code a little more compact.